# Good practice to use a different DbContext class for every page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, code-first

I am in the process of optimizing and refactoring a large ERP-type ASP.NET application to achieve a faster development experience.
We currently have a large model (600+ tables/entities) that is created when the application starts which take around 15 seconds. (At this point, we are using NHibernate with code-first mappings)

I am trying to achieve the fastest rendering of the page after compilation is done.

I was wondering if it would be a good practice to have one DbContext per page which would include only the required entities/mappings to use this page.
Every page is viewed as a distinct element and can be carried around on its own.

EDIT: I am not talking about reusing an instance of a DbContext, but a different object with different DbSets. A different instance would be created for every request.

Comment: So you're using NHibernate currently and switching to Entity Framework?

Comment: @mason: I'm considering it if it improves our development workflow. The limited LINQ support is also becoming a problem.

Comment: Yes, it's a good practice.

Answer (score 5):

> I was wondering if it would be a good practice to have one DbContext
>   per page which would include only the required entities/mappings to
>   use this page.

I don't think this is a good idea to have one dedicated DbContext type per page.

- Each DbContext's type model will hold a memory footprint during the whole app domain lifetime. I would say the footprint will be something like 5MB for around 20 entity types.
- You will have a hard time defining the boundaries of each of your DbContext types ( ignoring navigation properties of your entities on a case by case basis will force you to define a lot of dedicated mapping configurations ). Not that this a bad idea, but I guess the Linq support would be almost useless, and I think a micro-orm would be better suited for this approach.

You may also go for bounded contexts : Separate your domain model into sets of entities corresponding to the same concern (let's say at most 50 entities per concern) and use a dedicated DbContext type per concern (without navigation properties across entities of different DbContexts). Note that you may define very simple cross-concern (mostly readonly) mappings to use cross concern concepts across your whole app (for example, a `UserSummary` entity exposing the main properties of the `User` entity)

As to speed-up startup, I guess this can help [3 STEPS FOR FAST ENTITYFRAMEWORK 6.1 CODE-FIRST STARTUP PERFORMANCE](https://www.fusonic.net/en/blog/3-steps-for-fast-entityframework-6.1-code-first-startup-performance/)

Answer (score 3):

It's a good practice to use `DbContext` per each request.

If you render partial pages on your View it's better if you still use same context.

Your context disposed automatically at the end of your request in general (Of cource there are some exceptions if you create your context on application start for example but you shouldn't do this anyway) but it's better dispose it manually at the end of request.

But if you talking about best perfomance i was on conference where StackOverflow team talking about how SO working (it's written on MVC as well).

They say that they don't use **EF** or any other **ORM** at all becouse it creates lots of intermediate objects and `GarbageCollector` can't dispose it fast enought. So they writing all on good old plain **ADO.NET**

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network), Stackoverflow uses LINQ to SQL and Dapper.

Comment: @Win can't argue this. But [in this report](http://www.highload.ru/2015/abstracts/1963.html) they talking that they don't use ORM.

Comment: This is all fine but it's not answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

So far this is exactly the model I've been using and it all went just fine. The DbContext should exist for as little as possible and should represent the database context (get it?) for the related actions you are operating. It's pretty much the same as having a new controller instance for every request in ASP.NET MVC.

After the first instance gets created, the subsequent ones are blazing fast.

As a matter of fact, trying to use the DbContext more than would be natural (caching it maybe), will get you in a heap of trouble. That is because of its state tracking which tends to grow like prince charming. Also, doing direct updates or deletes via attaching entities in an old context where an entity with that primary key had already been loaded before (maybe in some unrelated operation) will throw an exception.

Bottom line: it's not called DbCONTEXT for nothing. Use it shortly and then dispose it.

EDIT: This post refers solely to Entity Framework. I am not familiar with NHibernate.

Comment: I am not talking about reusing an instance of a DbContext, but a different object with different DbSets.

Comment: @Jason For that you would need to define different DbContext types in which you could include only the needed tables. For example, in database first, you don't select all the tables, but only the ones you'd use. Yes, it would be faster (but I bet the difference would be tiny), but having to manage all those types would be a major pain. Imagine you'd have to edit tens of DbContext classes just to add a new field.

Comment: @Jason It might work ok if you keep the DbContext types number small. It also might make sense for separating the database into large subsets (like having a financial info DbContext, one for personnel, one for stocks and so on). But if the data is tightly related... you see where I'm going...

Comment: Is there an easy way to reuse mapping across different DbContext? I guess that would simplify the whole process.

Comment: @Jason None that I'm aware of, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework 6 added support for using multiple models in a single database, including migrations. But each of the models needs to be independent from the other models, i.e. no shared tables and entities. Sharing entities can be done but migrations become more complicated.

This blog post, [Data Points - EF6 Code First Migrations for Multiple Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948104.aspx), goes into details of what is supported in EF6 and also has links to other presentations about sharing entities across models.

If you are mainly focusing on the amount of time spent during development then you might be able to make individual DbContexts for each page or group of pages which don't have any migrations enabled (and hence there shouldn't be any problems with sharing entities between DbContexts). Then you have a single DbContext which you use in production containing all of the entities and has migrations. Give them all interfaces and tie it together with dependency injection and you can then easily switch between DbContexts for development, testing and production.